# Set early bird registration by date

Tags: mysql, date

I have an event date, m_date, 2011-11-11

I have days prior to event, e_date, which is an int, 30

And Now()

How do i perform a query return true if todays date, Now() is < e_date - m_date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

```
$event_date_in_seconds = strtotime($event_date);
$days_prior = 30;

if (time() < (strtotime("-".$days_prior." second", $event_date_in_seconds)))
   return true;
```

In MySQL, not really sure how you want it to return true, but it'd be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOW() < DATE_SUB(event_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Comment: shouldnt $days_prior be converted to seconds?

Comment: Not a problem, I really appreciate the help. I would prefer mysql though

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your help and fast responses!!